# Show Progress while processing post request in golang webapp

Tags: go, progress

On receiving the post request, the posted data passes through several functions and when the processing is done, it displays a suitable web page. The problem is that there is a bit of delay since the functions for processing data are somewhat time taking.

Is there a way I can show clients the progress of data processing? Essentially, when a data is posted, I want some messages to be dislayed like

```
Loading data (xyz conversion done)
Loading data (xyz added to stream)
```

I am using golang for my backend and julienschmidt's httprouter .

Answer (score 1):

`w ResponseWriter` in your Handlers `func(w ResponseWriter,r *Request)` most likely implements `http.Flusher` interface. So you can

```
io.WriteString(w, "Loading data (xyz conversion done)")
w.(http.Flusher).Flush() //you must assert it implements
io.WriteString(w, payload)
```

flush to client before all work done.
To take more control you even can hijack connection

```
conn, bufrw, err :=w.(http.Hijacker).Hijack()
defer conn.Close()
bufrw.WriteString("Loading data (xyz conversion done)")
bufrw.Flush()
bufrw.WriteString("Loading data (xyz added to stream)")
bufrw.Flush()
```

and speak raw TCP.

Answer (score 1):

Showing a progress indicator is the job of your client-side code (while making an asynchronous call).

HTTP is a request–response protocol. Responses have a standard format (including a status line, headers, message body). They are not sent in parts.

What you are suggesting would be relevant to a TCP connection but not HTTP.